# Replace replace pattern containing newline without breaking stream

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've got some Plesk servers I'm forced to work with, and I've written a script to handle backups via the CLI. The trouble is that if the Plesk backup tool encounters a problem backing up a domain the only way it will output *useful* information is if the entire backup job is run with a verbose flag. The trouble with that is it makes the tool output `Domains [0/1]\n` once per second while the job runs, and if it runs for an hour then you've got 3600 lines of useless info pushing *useful* info out of the buffer. For example:

```
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
Domains [0/1]
-------------- Start print backup log hire --------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <execution-result status="success" log-location="/usr/local/psa/PMM/sessions/2013-11-08-114156.109/migration.result"/>
-------------- End print backup log hire --------------
```

What I've been trying to do is craft a command to pipe this through that simply replaces `\nDomains [\d+/\d+]` with a hashmark so the above will turn into:

```
Domains [0/1]########
-------------- Start print backup log hire --------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <execution-result status="success" log-location="/usr/local/psa/PMM/sessions/2013-11-08-114156.109/migration.result"/>
-------------- End print backup log hire --------------
```

I have found ways using `sed`'s `N` flag as in `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s:\nDomains \[[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+\]:#:g'` or some fudgery with `tr`, but this causes the entire output to be buffered and the output only generated once the backup script has completely finished.

How can I get this replacement to work in-stream so I can still get a live status output?

The command in question is:

```
ssh ${server} sudo ${pbackup} domains-name -v --output-file=${ftp_spec} $domain 2>&1 | \
    sed ':a;N;$!ba;s:\nDomains \[0/1\]:X:g'
```

**Edit:** I also came up with a short test script to generate the relevant text without running a dozen backups:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "blah blah pre text"
i=0
while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do
        echo 'Domains [0/1]'
        sleep 1
        i=$(($i + 1))
done
echo "blah blah post text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided it was probably a good idea to write my own little tool, and my go-to language is PHP. It's not pretty, but it gets the job done if you're interested in matching and replacing single trailing line breaks.

```
<?php
if( $argc != 3 ) {
    echo "Bad args";
    exit(1);
} else if( ! $in = fopen('php://stdin', 'r') ) {
    echo "Could not open stdin.\n";
    exit(1);
}
while( $line = fgets($in) ) {
    $oline = preg_replace($argv[1], $argv[2], $line);
    if( is_null($oline) ) {
        echo "PCRE Error.";
        exit(1);
    } else { echo $oline; }
}
fclose($in);
```

and it is invoked like:

```
ssh ${server} sudo ${pbackup} domains-name -v --output-file=${ftp_spec} $domain 2>&1 | \
    php streamedit.php ':Domains \[\d+/\d+\]\n:' '#'
```

and produces output:

```
#######-------------- Start print backup log hire --------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <execution-result status="success" log-location="/usr/local/psa/PMM/sessions/2013-11-08-142159.357/migration.result"/>
-------------- End print backup log hire --------------
```

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it gets the job done.

If anyone has a different/better solution I am more than willing to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

As  far as I can tell there is no way to get sed to output anything without a newline. You could write a sed script that outputs the specified amount of hashes and a newline when there is a line that you want to keep. Your current script doesn't do this, instead it just reads the whole input and only then does the editing.

If you don't need the #-signs, you could use

```
| fgrep -v 'Domains [0/1]'
```

to simply ignore those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
| sed -n -u "/Domains \[0\/1\]/ !p"
```

the -u is a stream version of sed, sed is working until the first EOF but don't buffer the entire result before giving the result